# How do I use Puppet's ralsh with resource types provided by modules?

Tags: postgresql, puppet

I have installed the postgresql module from Puppetforge.

How can I query Postgresql resources using `ralsh` ?

None of the following works:

```
# ralsh postgresql::db
# ralsh puppetlabs/postgresql::db
# ralsh puppetlabs-postgresql::db
```

I was hoping to use this to get a list of databases (including attributes such as character sets) and user names/passwords from the current system in a form that I can paste into a puppet manifest to recreate that setup on a different machine.

Comment: What is your specific problem?

Comment: get a list of databases and user names/passwords from the current system in a form that I can paste into a puppet manifest to recreate that setup

Comment: How far are you getting?  What is happening when you try?

Comment: any particular reason why you're not using psql to get the information?

Comment: I'd like to use Puppet to manage this without needing to dig into both psql and the postgresql puppet module to figure this out. Ralsh seems like a great idea for a cross-platform, cross-tool way to capture the current state.

Answer (score 1):

In principle, any `puppet client` gets the current state of your system from another program called `Facter`. You should create a custom `Fact` (a module of `Facter`), and then included into your puppet client. Afterwards, I think you could call this custom `Fact` from `ralsh`.

More information about creating a custom `Fact` can be found in [here](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/custom_facts.html).

In creating your own `Fact`, you should execute your SQL query and then save the result into particular variable.

Comment: And is there such a Fact in the postgresql module?